# primitive functions (derivatives)

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Calculate the antiderivatives (primitive functions) F and G of :
$$ f(x) = \frac{4x}{x^{2}+1} $$ and : $$ g(x) = 2^{x}.\sin(x) $$
Show that the derivatives of the functions you found are F´(x) = f(x) and G´(x) = g(x)

Comment: Where is $g(x)$?

Comment: You learned how to do antiderivatives by substitution?  What is a likely substitution for this case?

Comment: ahh sory :$$ g(x) = 2^{x}.\sin(x) $$

Answer (score 3):

a line without words: $$f(x)=2\left(\frac{2x}{x^2+1}\right)$$